# How to add fuzzy completion (like Sublime Text palette) to ZSH

Tags: zsh, sublimetext, fuzzy-search

I changed by shell from bash to zsh and I was wondering if this was possible to fuzzy complete commands just like with the Sublime Text palette. I think that this concept of searching, completing must be everywhere. It's a huge time saving.

**Example**:

`cd dcmts -> cd Documents`

`cd dwnls/mnf -> cd Downloads/MyNewFolder`

I saw the following project and it's not really convincing.

[zsh-fuzzy-match](https://github.com/tarruda/zsh-fuzzy-match)

And it's seems to be possible to define some settings or algorithms to configure the behaviour of zsh on completion.

`zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _match _approximate`

`zstyle ':completion:*:match:*' original only`

`zstyle ':completion:*:approximate:*' max-errors 10 numeric`

The problem of the two previous solutions is that folders doesn't appears on top of the list when completing while it's often what the user wants.

If you have any interesting `.zshrc` that statisfy fuzzy search, it would be interesting.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you give an example of *folders doesn't appears on top of the list when completing*? It *seems* you have something in your configuration breaking things for you. Zsh by default will only complete `cd` with directories:

```
zsh -f # new Zsh with only default configs
% zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _match _approximate
% zstyle ':completion:*:approximate:*' max-errors 3 numeric
% mkdir test && cd test
% mkdir etc && touch et0
% autoload -U compinit && compinit 
% cd et0[TAB] # removes the 'et0' and replaces it with 'etc'.
```

FWIW, for "searching and completing everywhere" consider trying `predict` https://stackoverflow.com/a/17230878/766289 (I find it a little insane...)

Also, in Zsh you can do things like:

```
setopt auto_cd
alias -d build=/home/foo/very/long/path/build # dir alias
build # <-- changes into /home/foo/very/long/path/build
```

Or just

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' # match upper from lower case
cd d/m[TAB] # just type the initial letter of each dir
cd Downloads/MyNewFolder
```

I mean `cd d/m` requires less typing than `cd dwnls/mnf` ;-)

Comment: In fact, folders didn't appear on top because I wasn't typing the cd command but just the folder name. So this is normal. Your totally right for the fact that `cd d/m` is much quicker that `cd dwnls/mnf`. I will try to use it. And the predict solution is just SO AMAZING. I love it, thanks ;)

Comment: The problem is that following your first example `cd abc[TAB]` also completes to `cd etc/`.  For me this is less helpful where I often find it too aggressive in what it will correct.  You do have some degree to tune it, but I don't think it's really the fuzzy matching the question was hoping for.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you check out [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), a general purpose fuzzy finder that can process lines from standard input. It's written in Ruby and not a zsh script, so it might not be what you're looking for, but just like zsh-fuzzy-match it sets up `CTRL-T` binding for your shell and it's pretty straightforward to customize its behavior.

The GIF below shows how it works.

[image]

**EDIT:**

fzf was entirely rewritten in Go and now comes with [fuzzy completion support](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#fuzzy-completion-for-bash-and-zsh) for zsh and bash.

Comment: It's a good work. I am waiting for the module to be develop for zsh. The developer seems to wait for pull requests. Thanks for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting this

```sh
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'r:[[:ascii:]]||[[:ascii:]]=** r:|=* m:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}'
```

Into your `zshrc`. It does exactly what you want, and it does it to `zsh`'s own completion system, not to an external completion system.

Comment: Can You explain the argument after "matcher-list" in some detail? It seems to work after a short test (with `ls`), but has some glitches: absolute paths are not completed, and matches in subdirs are displayed in the completion list but removed from the commandline, e.g. `cd /` then `ls etc/p<tab>` lists some files in /etc that have a p in their name but my command line is set to `ls etc/`.